# How to Recursively Change all FILE Permissions without Changing DIRECTORY (and subdirectoruy) Permissions?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

How do I change the file permissions of all files in a directory (and subdirectories) without changing any directory or subdirectory permissions?

Comment: Chmod -R pathofparentdir

Comment: `find <dir> -type f -exec chmod <perms> {} \;`

Comment: Biffen's answer is the way to go. @rups, did you carefully read the question ? directory permissions must not be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using `find`:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type f | xargs chmod 755
```

Comment: I think you have to add `-d '\n' ` after `xargs` command  because files names are separated by newline character